# Rails 5 app - How to perform testing on screenshot differences?

Tags: automated-tests, cucumber, capybara, ruby-on-rails-5, poltergeist

I am using cucumber + capybara + poltegeist driver in my rails 5 application. How to do image comparison testing for the above combination ?

I am able to save screenshot on test scenario execution.  But, additionally I like to compare the screenshot image of previous and current ones and report for any differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using [RSpec Page Regression](https://github.com/rprt/rspec-page-regression) for screenshot diff-ing. You'll be able to compare screenshots of pages rendered with the poltergeist driver and they provide a nice DSL for including them in RSpec feature specs. Also, you can set a threshold of how "different" a screenshot can be (the % of pixels different).

The downside is that you'd be using a combination of Cucumber and RSpec for integration testing.

Comment: Thanks, my current requirement is cucumber + capybara with poltegeist driver for integration testing.